# Задача питон Декоратор

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

Задали в универе задачу по Декораторам в питоне
Суть такова:
Имеется функция, которая вычисляет некоторое значение и возвращает его в качестве результата работы. Функция вычисляется достаточно долго, ничего не выводит на экран, не пишет в файлы и зависит только от переданных аргументов.
Реализуйте декоратор, который «ускорит» вычисления этой функции. Для каждого набора параметров необходимо запоминать результат выполнения функции и возвращать его, если снова передали такой набор параметров.

Вроде я придумал алгоритм который "ускорит" функцию, но не могу понять как это функцию запихнуть в декоратор.
Вот вариант без функции и декораторов

```
d={}
i = 0
while i<5:
   value=int(input("Введите первое число: "))
   value2=int(input("Введите второе число: "))
   c = [value,value2]
   key=value+value2
   if key in d.keys(): 
      d[key] = c
      print("Такое ключ уже есть в списке:",*d.keys())
   else:
      d[key] = c
      print("Добавили новое значение")
   i=i+1
```

Помогите пожалуйста создать функцию и запихнуть все в декоратор

Comment: Нужно в декораторе помнить входные данные функции и результат. И если происходит повторный вызов функции, то сразу вернуть результат

Comment: Я вроде понял что Декоратор это то что выполняется до функции или после.
Но не могу понять сам синтаксис

Comment: Декоратор -- это функция (или функтор)

Comment: [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Имеется функция, которая вычисляет некоторое значение и возвращает его
>   в качестве результата работы

Пусть это будет возведение в степень:

```
def func(a, b):
    return a ** b
```

Теперь сделаем декоратор, который будет помнить (кеширование) аргументы и результат вызова, и перед вызовом подконтрольной функции проверит свой кеш перед тем как вызывать функцию:

```
def memoize_func(f):
    memo = dict()

    def func(*args):
        print(f'Run with args={args}, memo={memo}')
        if args not in memo:
            memo[args] = f(*args)
        return memo[args]

    return func
```

Чтобы функция работала с декоратором его нужно написать перед функцией как `@<decorator>`:

```
@memoize_func
def func(a, b):
    print(f'    Run func({a}, {b})')
    return a ** b
```

Теперь посмотрим как работает:

```
print(func(3, 5), '\n')
print(func(3, 4), '\n')
print(func(3, 2), '\n')
print(func(3, 5), '\n')
print(func(3, 4), '\n')
print(func(3, 5), '\n')
```

По консоли видно, что для сохраненных в кеше аргументах не происходит вызова функции, чтобы получить результат:

```
Run with args=(3, 5), memo={}
    Run func(3, 5)
243 

Run with args=(3, 4), memo={(3, 5): 243}
    Run func(3, 4)
81 

Run with args=(3, 2), memo={(3, 5): 243, (3, 4): 81}
    Run func(3, 2)
9 

Run with args=(3, 5), memo={(3, 5): 243, (3, 4): 81, (3, 2): 9}
243 

Run with args=(3, 4), memo={(3, 5): 243, (3, 4): 81, (3, 2): 9}
81 

Run with args=(3, 5), memo={(3, 5): 243, (3, 4): 81, (3, 2): 9}
243
```

Comment: Гм, `if x not in memo:` - наверное, что-то не то (внутри `memoize_func.func`) - навеное, `args[0]` вместо `x`

Comment: @EurobeatIntensifies, вы правы, опечатался :)

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется чтобы декоратор в программе помнил вызовы функции, можно сделать "в лоб" следующим образом, но так лучше не делать, как эскперимент. Используя 2.7:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def my_decorator(out=[]):
    def decorator(func1):
        def a_wrapper(*arg1, **arg2):
            if arg1 in out:
                print "Уже запускалась функция с такими параметрами {}".format(arg1)
            else:
                out.append(arg1)
                answer = func1(*arg1, **arg2)
        return a_wrapper
    return decorator

@my_decorator()
def any_func(x, y):
    return x + y

for i in [(1,2), (2,3), (-1, 4), (1, 2)]:
    any_func(*i)
# Уже запускалась функция с такими параметрами (1, 2)
print my_decorator.__defaults__
# ([(1, 2), (2, 3), (-1, 4)],)
```

Comment: 1) У вас так `out` в `def my_decorator(out=[]):` станет общим для разных функций :) Создайте `@my_decorator()
def any_func2(x, y):
    return x + y` и вызовите `any_func(1, 1)` и `any_func2(1, 1)`. Предупреждение сработает второй раз. Это особенность питона, поэтому вместо `out=[]` указывайте `out=None` и внутри функции: `if out is None: out = []`. Правда, тогда `__defaults__` сломается 2) Сделайте `print` функцией и у тогда код станет совместим с питоном3 ;)

Comment: 1) если None - кэша вызовов угу не будет - но  "это не баг - это фича")) 2) никак не заставлю себя "принтить" в скобках